# KernalDistance() in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i am beginner matlab programs .I have a code in matlab

```
   Dist(k,j) = KernelDistance(data(k,j),data(k,i),h_square)
```

i don't know the correct function of **KernelDistance()**. And i have a doubt that is this KernalDistance function is same to calculating kernal density?

can any one help me to know about this function **KernelDistance()**?

Comment: What do you get if you type `edit KernelDistance` in your command window? Otherwise, I agree with @Philippe's answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find this function on the MathWorks website nor in the index browser, it means it is not a built-in function of Matlab.

So, either you understand the script you are using and can recreate a function on your own or otherwise you should see if the website where you took this code also provides this function.

Finally, it looks like this question might be related to your studies. If it is, I would suggest you to state it in the question.